# Can someone explain this command?

Tags: linux

Please someone explain this command.

```
kill -9 `ps -ef|grep 'kav'|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Also anyone please tell me where to learn command line programs?

Comment: for `|` (pipe) and `\`...\`` (command substitution, should better be written as `$(...)`) see the documentation of `bash` and look for `bash` tutorials, for the individual commands like `kill`, `ps`, `grep`, `awk`, see their man page, e.g. `man kill` etc.

Comment: `grep kav` will match any line from ps that has `kav` as part of the user, the process or any process argument, so is not a well-written command.  Better would be to use awk to match the specific field and get rid of the `grep`s

Answer (score 2):

One the best ways for beginners to get familiar with Gnu/Linux is to start by learning about LPIC (It has BASH programming in itself, too).

And if you forget any command or if you want take a look at arguments or you want to learn about a new command, you can read manual pages using `man COMMAND` in terminal. (For example `man grep`)

In this example:

1) `kill -9` terminates a process.

2) `ps` shows current processes

3) `grep` print lines that match special patterns

4) `awk '{print $2}'` shows second column

And `|` (pipe) gives the output of the previous command, as an input to the next command.